# How GOTO statement in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, dsl, transformation, goto, continuations

I saw this [nice blog post about a Scala continuations](http://blog.richdougherty.com/2009/03/goto-in-scala.html) that 'emulates' a `GOTO` statement in the Scala language. (read more about [Continuations here](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2096))

I would like to have the same in the programming language Groovy. I think it's possible within a [Groovy compiler phase transformation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Compiler+Phase+Guide).

I'm working on an Domain-Specific Language (DSL), and preferred embedded in Groovy. I would like to have the `GOTO` statement, because the DSL is an unstructured language (and is generated from workflow diagrams). I need a 'labeled' goto statement, not to line numbers.

The DSL is a language for workflow definitions, and because there are no restrictions for the arrows between nodes, a `goto` is needed. (or unreadable code with `while` etc)

As a beginner of Groovy and Scala I don't know If I can translate the Scala solution to Groovy, but I don think there are continuations in Groovy.

I'm looking for an algorithm/code for emulating labeled goto's in Groovy. One algorithm I had in mind is using `eval` repeatedly; doing the `eval` when your are at a `goto`.
The DSL is evaluated with an `eval` already.

I'm not looking for a 'while' loop or something, but rather translating this code so that it works (some other syntax is no problem)

```
label1: 
a();
b();
goto label1;
```

PS:
I don't prefer the discussion if I should really use/want the GOTO statement. The DSL is a specification-language and is probably not coping with variables, efficiency etc.

PS2: Some other keyword then `GOTO` can be used.

Comment: Just a sidenote, labelled goto can be simulated more easily than by continuations...

Comment: @Gabriel: So can you give me any glues?

Comment: No, I have no glue:)... I don't know what constraints your DSL really has and I don't know much Groovy, but one way to deal with goto might be to have array/list/map of closure constants and one method executing current index/key, which might be changed with goto.

Comment: @Gabriel but why is labelled then easier then non-labelled?

Comment: Did I write this? Non-labelled is basically every statement has an auto-assigned label, e.g. line number. You can simulate that by making the user write inside array literal - Program[]{statement1, stemaent2,...,stetementN}; Then you can have while loop going through the array using incrementing index, which can change when you detect goto with valid index in the program array. You could have labels in the same way, but yu would have to add a Map<String,Integer> which will assign an index to a label when label statement detected.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to tell a little bit more about the language you are trying to build, perhaps it's simple enough that dealing with transformations would be overengineering.
Playing with the AST is something groovy people have been doing for years and it's really powerful.
The spock framework guys rewrite the tests you create annotating the code with labels.  http://code.google.com/p/spock/

Hamlet D'Arcy has given several presentations on the matter. Several posts can also be found on his blog.  http://hamletdarcy.blogspot.com/
Cedric Champeau describes an interesting transformation he built and its evolution http://www.jroller.com/melix/

Probably missing lots of other guys but those I remember.
A possible starting points that you probably already know but are really useful.  http://groovy.codehaus.org/Compile-time+Metaprogramming+-+AST+Transformations
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Building+AST+Guide

Long story short, I'd say its quite possible

Comment: I think the AST transformations are a good direction. I update the start post with more information about the DSL.

Comment: @Julian sorry, i lost track of this.
i can give you a hint on ast transformations, but now that i reread your post, i believe the language you want to build will need quite a lot of thinking.
basically, if you want a language that is completely structure free, you will need more than one trick to write it in a structured language. injected loops will be quite restrictive with regards to nesting, you might have to redesign the whole sequencing, as someone suggested.
in any case, if you want to play with ast, this is an extremely simplistic example
http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/418002

Answer (score 1):

You won't get anywhere trying this, as `goto` is a [reserved word in Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reserved+Words) (as it is in Java), so using it in your DSL will be problematic.

It's not a [reserved word in Scala](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/scala/9780596801908/type-less-do-more/reservedwords), so this isn't an issue

Comment: So then we use the keyword `gooto`? It's about the behavior, not about the actual keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate `if` and `goto` with `while` loops. It won't be pretty, it will introduce lots of unnecessary code-blocks, but it should work for any function. There is some proof that this is always possible to rewrite code like that, but of course being possible does not mean it's nice or easy.

Basically you move all local variables to the beginning of the function and add a `bool takeJump` local variable. Then add a `while(takeJump){`+`}` pair for any goto+label pair and set the flag before the while and before the end of the while to the value you want.

But to be honest I don't recommend that approach. I'd rather use a library that allows me to build an AST with labels and gotos and then translates that directly to byte-code.

Or use some other language built on the java vm that does support `goto`. I'm sure there is such a language.

Comment: I know and therefore in the start post I said: "I'm not looking for a 'while' loop or something" ;)

Comment: It gets somewhat easier with if and while, but it is not pretty and it might require 3/2 increase of code length in worst case.

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing this out there, perhaps you could have a scoped switch case

So if your DSL says this:

```
def foo() {
   def x = x()
   def y
   def z
   label a:
     y = y(x)
   if(y < someConst) goto a
   label b: 
    z = y(z)
    if(z > someConst) goto c
    x = y(y(z+x))
    z = y(x)
   label c:
    return z; 
}
```

Your "compiler" can turn it into this:

```
def foo() {
    String currentLABEL = "NO_LABEL"
    while(SCOPED_INTO_BLOCK_0143) {
       def x
       def y
       def z
       def retval
       switch(currentLABEL) {
       case "NO_LABEL":
          x = x()
       case "LABEL_A"
          y = y(x)

          if(y < someConst) {
            currentLABEL = "LABEL_A"
           break
          }
       case "LABEL_B"
          z = y(z)

          if(z > someConst) {
            currentLabel = "LABEL_C"
            break
          }
          x = y(y(z+x))
          z = y(x)
       case "LABEL_C"
          SCOPED_INTO_BLOCK_0143 = false
          retval = z
       }
    }
    return retval
}
```