# Groovy Closure Syntax

Tags: groovy, closures

If I write

```
test = {
  println("Hello world");
}
```

That creates a closure in a variable called *test* that I can invoke with `test();`

However

```
test: {
  println("Hello world");
}
```

Immediately invokes the closure and I cannot invoke it with `test();`

What is the purpose of the second syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like a plain old labeled block of java code.  Not Groovy closure syntax.  Which would just allow you to scope the local variables within the block.  If it is an alternative syntax I would avoid it.

```
public void do(){
 test:{
   String hello = "hello";
 }

 anotherTest:{
   String hello = "hello";
 }
}
```

Comment: It's just a labelled block of code as you say, and not another way of defining a closure.  Of course, the OP may have been trying to make a map of closures like: `map = [ test:{ println 'Hi' } ]` which is a perfectly valid closure definition

Comment: Thank you for the additional insight.  I almost deleted my answer after I posted it because I might just be acting as 'Captain Obvious' and not providing any help.

Answer (score 1):

When doing so, you don't define a closure, but rather label a code block.

Indeed, as [this page states](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/JN2535-Control), Groovy supports old-school labels.

Yup. it's also a **big** surprise to me.

Comment: The link is dead, so I provide more information about GOTO labels in Groovy. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4937416/352054